# Redirect mysqldump to a file from a bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

From the command line I can do a dump and redirect it to a file without any issue.

```
sql=mysql_dump.sql
run_sql="mysqldump -u root -p scope_import > $sql"
$run_sql
```

When I run it from this script it gives an error: Not such table '>' so its no seeing the > as a redirect rather a table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply:

```
sql=mysql_dump.sql
mysqldump -u root -p scope_import > $sql
```

(I hope I haven't misunderstood your question).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to fix something else by adding quotes.  I'm not to bash scripting. :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong quotes

```
sql=mysql_dump.sql
run_sql="mysqldump -u root -p scope_import"
$run_sql > "$sql"
```